# Lisp development on Mac

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sublimetext2, sublimetext

So I am getting ready to learn some lisp. I am thinking of learning Common Lisp. It seems like using emacs is the best IDE for that. However, I have been using Sublime Text 2 for a little while now so if I could stick to that, that would be awesome.

Does anyone else do lisp development with that? Can you make it as good of an IDE for lisp as Emacs with Slime etc? I see the Sublime REPL plugin but not sure how that compares.

Comment: The [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin is really great for all sorts of languages, and even if ST2 development lags, as @Slomojo mentions below, wuub is pretty active with SublimeREPL, and is very responsive to users' questions. ST2/SublimeREPL will never replace emacs/slime/extensions galore when it comes to complete Lisp integration, but depending on your workflow it may be a suitable substitute. Ultimately, it'll come down to what you're familiar and comfortable with. Try them both and compare!

Comment: Clozure CL is available on the mac app store, and includes a repl and simple cocoa editor (written in CL) as well. It also provides slime support etc. If you haven't tried it, If you're new to the whole thing I suggest it and M-.  (that's option-dot on a mac) will do wonders -- for example. download Clozure CL, type (list 1 2 3) at the repl and press Option-Period while your cursor is over the word 'list'  :)

Answer (score 2):

Emacs itself is essentially a Lisp environment, and I'd say it was ideal for working with Lisp, for this reason, and also because of the excellent SLiME mode.

You could certainly work with Lisp with SublimeText but there'd be no advantage over using Emacs, and a fairly large set of disadvantages.

On the Mac, grab the latest Emacs mac port build from https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port (there is straight compilation, homebrew and pre-built binary installers on offer)

Then install packages via elpa.

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

There's so much happening in Emacs recently, the last 12 months or so have seen huge numbers of packages added, check @melpa_emacs there's things being updated every day.

Don't forget, when Jon Skinner can't be bothered to keep developing SublimeText, it'll go the exact same way as TextMate, ie. down the toilet.